# Stripe account.create returns customer_id instead of account_id

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement the following flow in Stripe Connect:

1. Customer -> My platform -> 2. Customer.

So I looked up the documentation and used the Connect api. So I found out that I have to create account to make transfer. The problem is that the `account.create` method returns `customer_id` instead of `account_id`. Looks like it still uses `stripe.customers.create` instead of `stripe.accounts.create`

This is how I create the account:

```
// When a user is created, register them with Stripe
exports.createStripeAccount = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
  const account = await stripe.accounts.create({type: 'express', requested_capabilities: ['card_payments', 'transfers'], email: user.email});
  return admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).set({account_id: account.id});
});
```

In this case the account.id starts with "**cus_**" which indicates that it is a customer not an account. Correct me if I am wrong here.

I could not find any questions about this while searching the web. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the version of the stripe API you are using?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec The Stripe API version I am using is v3

Comment: The API doc says for the `type` that "Currently (it) must be custom, as only Custom accounts may be created via the API." Since the account id starts by `cus_` this is maybe to indicate that it is a custom account? (even if I expect the API to return an error instead of a wrong response...)??  https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create. Can you share the JSON you receive back?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec wow, that was the case. Gotta agree with you that the response is so misleading.

Comment: Glad I could help you: I'll write a response along these lines! Just to be sure: when you set the type to `custom`, do you still receive an `account.id` starting with "cus_"?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec With the type of `custom` I do get the right id as it now starts with  `acct_` instead of  `cus_`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Stripe API [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create) indicates for the `type` argument that "currently (it) **must be `custom`**, as only Custom accounts may be created via the API."

In your case you were passing a `type` of `express`:

```
const account = await stripe.accounts.create({type: 'express'....})
```

As you have confirmed (see comments above) **when passing a `type` of `custom` you**  "do get the right `id` as it now starts with `acct_` instead of `cus_`".

Comment: Can you also clarify for me, do I need to create customer also if I do want to make charge and afterwards make a transfer to other account?

Comment: Wow.. I haven't worked with the stripe API for more than 6 months! :-) I would have to dive into the doc. I'll have a look later today!

Comment: No problem at all. Thank you very much for your explenaition :)